# TypeError: Cart() takes no arguments

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

This is views.py file from the cart section where I want to add product, remove product and show product details in the cart. Error is : Cart() takes no arguments.

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from django.views.decorators.http import require_POST
from ecommerce.models import Product
from .cart import Cart
from .forms import CartAddProductForm


@require_POST
def cart_add(request, product_id):
    cart = Cart(request)
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=product_id)
    form = CartAddProductForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        cd = form.cleaned_data
        cart.add(product=product,
                 quantity=cd['quantity'],
                 override_quantity=cd['override'])
    return redirect('cart:cart_detail')


@require_POST
def cart_remove(request, product_id):
    cart = Cart(request)
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=product_id)
    cart.remove(product)
    return redirect('cart:cart_detail')


def cart_detail(request):
    cart = Cart(request)
    products = []
    for item in cart:
        item['update_quantity_form'] = CartAddProductForm(initial={
                            'quantity': item['quantity'],
                            'override': True})
    return render(request, 'cart/detail.html', {'cart': cart})
```

This is my cart.py file where shopping cart can be managed. Here is the method to add, remove, iteration over the items in the cart etc.

```
from decimal import Decimal
from django.conf import settings
from ecommerce.models import Product


class Cart:
    def __int__(self, request):
        """
        Initialize the cart.
        """
        self.session = request.session
        cart = self.session.get(settings.CART_SESSION_ID)
        if not cart:
            cart = self.session[settings.CART_SESSION_ID] = {}
        self.cart = cart

    def add(self, product, quantity=1, override_quantity=False):
        """
        Add a product to the cart or update its quantity
        """
        product_id = str(product.id)
        if product_id not in self.cart:
            self.cart[product_id] = {'quantity': 0, 'price': str(product.price)}

        if override_quantity:
            self.cart[product_id]['quantity'] = quantity
        else:
            self.cart[product_id]['quantity'] += quantity
        self.save()

    def save(self):
        self.session.modified = True

    def remove(self, product):
        """
        Remove a product from the cart.
        """
        product_id = str(product.id)
        if product_id in self.cart:
            del self.cart[product_id]
            self.save()

    def __iter__(self):
        """
        Iterate over the items in the cart and het the products
        from the database
        """
        product_ids = self.cart.keys()
        products = Product.objects.filter(id_in=product_ids)
        cart = self.cart.copy()
        for product in products:
            cart[str(product.id)]['product'] = product
        for item in cart.values():
            item['price'] = Decimal(item['price'])
            item['total_price'] = item['price'] * item['quantity']
            yield item

    def __len__(self):
        """
        Count all the items in the cart
        """
        return sum(item['quantity'] for item in self.cart.values())

    def get_total_price(self):
        return sum(Decimal(item['price']) * item['quantity'] for item in self.cart.values())

    def clear(self):
        del self.session[settings.CART_SESSION_ID]
        self.save()
```

Traceback Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\bbkra\PycharmProjects\djangoProject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\bbkra\PycharmProjects\djangoProject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\bbkra\PycharmProjects\djangoProject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\http.py", line 43, in inner
    return func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\bbkra\PycharmProjects\djangoProject\cart\views.py", line 10, in cart_add
    cart = Cart(request)
TypeError: Cart() takes no arguments
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I could see one mistake it should be [`__init__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__init__#object.__init__) method not `__int__` method.

That's why `Cart(request)` gave that error as `__init__()` was not actually called.